# Case insensitive string search using contains

Tags: c#, string, search, equals, contains

I need to search a directory for files and folders that **contain** the entered text,

I can see that `File.Name.Contains(txtSearch)` is the one that i need, but the problem is that it doesn't return true **when characters cases (lower/upper) don't match.**

Although `File.Name.Equals(txtSearch,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` solves this problem it requires that the the search string should be exactly the same.

Comment: Can you add some examples of 'problem' strings and what you want them to do. The given information is pretty basic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case insensitive contains(string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var position =  File.Name.IndexOf(txtSearch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Where `position` will be greater than **`-1`** if your "file name" contains any occurrence of the specified search string.

So..

```
if(position > -1){
    //found files, do something
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfect, it even returns more items than windows explorer!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var _reps = new List<string>(); // with variant data

_reps.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<string,string>(delegate(string srt){srt= srt.ToLower(); return srt;})).Contains("invisible")
```

this is by far the cleanest way i could find to do it